# Dijkstra algorithm for DAG

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dag

Assuming we have a K-Partite DAG (edges are directed from one level to the next) with edge weights either 0, 1 or 2.

We are looking for the shortest path between a node from group 0 to group k-1 (path of length k).

Is that correct that the algorithm will pick a path with minimal number of edges of weight 2? If so, how would one prove it?

Illustration of a 7-Partite graph:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Not neseccarily, it could take a route of a few $2$s and then a lot of $0$s, while there could be another route it wont take consisting of only $1$s. Djikstra will take the path of lowest sum of weights.

Comment: So the problem here is with the 0s. If the weights are 1s and 2s only, it's easy to prove minimal number of 2s. Adjusting the weights here to 1s, 2s and 3s can overcome the 0s problem and produce a solution with minimal 3s?

Comment: The problem can also be solved by removing the $1$s, its not an inherent problem of the $0$s. The problem is that there are $3$ options. So adjusting the weights to $1,2,3$ instead will still not solve the problem.

Comment: Notice that the question never states that edges are directed from one level to the next. In principle the shortest path could go, for example, from group $0$ to group $k-1$, then back to group $0$, and finally to group $k$. This means that the hop-lengths of the paths from group $0$ to group $k$ are not necessarily $k-1$ and hence Dijkstra's algorithm would not have the stated property even if weights were restricted to be in $\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Edited the question. edges are indeed directed from one level to the next.